# Using Here Documents in Termux

Tags: superuser, termux

I'm trying to run commands in a script that needs to be run as superuser. I tried doing this with here documents but wasn't successful. ( I used to be able to use it with `tsu` in Termux).

Does anyone know a reason why it shouldn't work or a way to get it to work.

Here is the code that used to work but doesn't work anymore.

```
#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash
... begining of script Just some regular commands

sudo touch s
tsu << EOF
    echo "Test" > s
    exit
EOF

echo after here doc
```

The results currently from this script is

```
echo "Test" > s
exit
after here doc
```

The 2 first lines should not appear at all and they should be in the file s. But the file s is empty.

I have also tried the following code but with the same results.

```
sudo touch s
sudo -s << EOF
    echo "Test" > s
    exit
EOF

echo after here doc
```

I have also googled this and haven't found anything to help me. All suggestion work in regular linux but not in Termux. [Here is one example of what I have tried.](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-script-with-su-and-here-document-ends-prematurely-4175413416/)

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Comment: I explained the behavior here: https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/1463#issuecomment-506874581

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you wrote there. Is there anyway I can accomplish what I'm trying to do? I would like to be able to run some commands in a script as root but not with sudo. The reason is that I'm having an issue with the PWD having (unreachable) prefixed to the path. [See here from @isrgish](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230388/termux-terminal-tsu-is-adding-unreachable-to-my-current-working-path). For `tsu` I have found a solution but when I try to run with sudo I still get the (unreachable) prefix.

Comment: remove all formatting whitespaces

Comment: @alecxs That doesn't seem to help.

Comment: okay forget it, i just remembered how i fixed some issues with mksh here documents. after reading github it's clear that termux su does not support that usage (like expected from linux su) you must run *su -c <cmd>* instead (like for magisk su)